# Find Periodicity in Lightcurve Using Lombscargle Periodogram(Astropy)

Tags: observational-astronomy, astrophysics, astropy, high-energy-astrophysics

How to find the Nyquist factor for unevenly sampled data like here.https://github.com/jakevdp/PracticalLombScargle/blob/master/figures/LINEAR_Example.ipynb ? I have time binned for 5 mins. I mean for every 5 mins I have some count/s. The time axis is in MJD. Any kind of help and suggestions would be great help. Thank you.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/41194/31410